# Query enabled but not expired users in AD

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How can I query AD to give me all users that are enabled, but not expired? I use the QuestAD tools with PowerShell but it doesn't have a "-NotExpired" option or equivalent with Get-QADUser.

I would prefer a PowerShell solution if possible to make it easier for me to play with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-QADUser -Enabled -SizeLimit 0 | where {-not $_.AccountIsExpired}
```

Comment: Bah, old question that has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - seems the object itself has a boolean "AccountIsExpired" flag I can test for.

Comment: Glad you've resolve this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.

Answer (score 0):

Get-QADUser -Enabled -AccountNeverExpires -SizeLimit 0

Comment: Doesn't cover accounts that are enabled and have an expiry date set in the future - which I want to see.

Comment: Check this parameters as well:

-AccountExpiresAfter <DateTime>
-AccountExpiresBefore <DateTime>

You can also reverse AccountNeverExpires: -AccountNeverExpires:$false

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a ADO ADSI query:

```
(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(|(accountExpires=9223372036854775807)(accountExpires=0)))
```

will give all the non-disabled accounts that don't expire.

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(accountExpires<=127818648000000000))
```

will give you all of the non-disabled user objects that expired before 1/16/2006

Here's an example of how to do an ADO ADSI query:

```
$strbase = "<LDAP://dc=ms,dc=com>" 
$strFilter = "(&(objectcategory=user)(useraccountcontrol=66048))" 

$strAttributes = "sAMAccountName,displayname" 
$strScope = "subtree" 
$strQuery = "$strBase;$strFilter;$strAttributes;$strScope" 

$objConnection = New-Object -comObject "ADODB.Connection" 
$objCommand = New-Object -comObject "ADODB.Command" 
$objConnection.Open("Provider=ADsDSOObject;") 
$objCommand.ActiveConnection = $objConnection 
$objCommand.CommandText = $strQuery 
$objRecordSet = $objCommand.Execute()
```

And according to this [post](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windows.powershell&tid=5d663805-22d9-4d1e-964f-ea3bbdcae243&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1)... you'll get the answer much quicker this way then you would with a cmdlet.  Also here is a great guide to [ADO ADSI](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOSearchTips.htm), it's references VBscript examples, but you can easily translate the concepts back to Powershell.